# I/zygote: Wrote stack traces to '[tombstoned]'

Tags: android, debugging

I'm debugging an Android app using LG Stylo4 phone (Android 8), and Android Studio 4.0.1. Where can I find the '[tombstoned]' file? Or what is it? Any help would be appreciated.